# Big O notation for these functions

Tags: c, performance, big-o

I want to solve that question but I am not sure if I am right or not. I found O(n^2-n)=O(n^2)

```
double fact(long i)
{
if (i==1 || i==0) return i;
else return i*fact(i-1);
}

funcQ2()
{
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
sum=sum+log(fact(i));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because there are thousands of questions on SO that are basically the same as yours.

Comment: @MoB.I literally searched a similiar example for 2 straight hours so, no

Comment: OK. Did my answer solve your question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fact` function is recursive, so you should start by writing the corresponding recurrence relation for the time complexity `T(i)`:

```
T(0) = 1             // base case i==0
T(1) = 1             // base case i==1
T(i) = T(i-1) + 1    // because fact calls itself on i-1 and does one multiplication afterwards
```

It's easy to see that the solution to this recurrence relation is `T(i) = i` for all `i > 0`, so `T(i) ∈ O(i)`.

Your second function `funcQ2` has no inputs, and assuming that `n` is a constant, its complexity is trivially O(1). If, on the other hand, you assume `n` to be an input parameter and want to measure time complexity with respect to `n`, it would be `O(n^2)` since you are calling `fact(i)` within the loop (standard arithmetic series).